# Connecting to SharePoint list from Excel

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have used data--> other sources-->web for connection

[image]

[image]

I see document and table on the left hand side. When I click on the table I see 30 rows on the right hand side. These 30rows are first page. In the SharePoint there are few more pages of this list. It just loaded first page rows in table.

I am connecting to a SharePoint path from Excel.
In excel, once I created the connection. I am able to view only 30 rows of the list. 30rows exists in the first page of SharePoint.

How can we load other pages of the SharePoint list in excel.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/474gS.jpg)
I am getting this message when I use the connection as
SharePoint list

Comment: Can you show us how you're doing what you're doing?  Screenshots, etc?  More context will help those trying to help you.

Comment: Hi Skin, I added two images please let me know if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the steps to connect:
[image]